# TypeScript: How to import all export functions from a JS file and then declare all those functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, export

I'm trying to create a .d.ts file for a js package so I can have typescript import functions from that package. The package is using CommonJs style to define its exported functions. (Not an es6 file.)

The package's main property from its `package.json` is directed to file: `index.js`. The `index.js` file is displayed as:

```
'use strict'

const Plugins = require('./Plugins')

module.exports = {
  plugins: Plugins
}
```

From the Plugis.js file:

```
module.exports.function1 = function1() {// function1 content};

module.exports.function2 = function2() {// function2 content};

module.exports.function3 = function3() {// function3 content};
```

In pure JavaScript, this works, and I can use any of `const Plugins` exported functions.

I'm trying to create a typescript version index.d.ts with a similar make up:

```
'use strict'

import Plugins from './Plugins'

module.exports = {
  plugins: Plugins
}
```

However, I get errors when I import the js package and attempt to use the exported functions. For example, can use `plugins.function1()`. I've been researching this topic and followed several examples, but I keep getting errors, such as if I declare the function I want to use, and examples use imports from es6 style files. what is correct approach to import all file's functions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. In addition to creating a index.d.ts I had to create a Plugins.d.ts file, then declare all the exported functions.

Plugins.d.ts:

```
declare export function1 = function1(): <Return value> {// function1 content};

declare export function2 = function2(): <Return value> {// function2 content};

declare export function3 = function3(): <Return value> {// function3 content};
```

For index.d.ts, my export and declare were off too, but I was able to correct it.
index.d.ts:

```
import * as Plugins from "./Plugins";

declare module "compatible-package-example" {
    export {Plugins}
}
```

Now when I import this package, I can use exported functions without issue.